# StorageTaskSnapshot is not working in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to store my image in firebase and retrieve it. But I got stuck because StorgeTaskSnapshot is not working, it says "undefined class/method". How do I fix it? Is it another issue due to the updated package version?

Here is a picture - [image: Please help me to resolve this]

Edit: I forgot to add code, so i am doing it -

Here's the complete file -

```
import 'dart:async';
//import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
//import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:telegramchatapp/Widgets/ProgressWidget.dart';
import 'package:telegramchatapp/main.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';


bool isLoading = false;

class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SettingsPageState createState() => _SettingsPageState();
}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {

  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<Null> logoutUser() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    await googleSignIn.signOut();

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });

    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        title: Text(
          'Account Settings',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (value) {
              logoutUser();
            },
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.logout,
                        color: Colors.grey[600],
                      ),
                      Text("Log out"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  value: "New Group",
                ),
              ];
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SettingsScreen(),
    );
  }
}


class SettingsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => SettingsScreenState();
}

class SettingsScreenState extends State<SettingsScreen> {

  TextEditingController nickNameTextEditingController;
  TextEditingController aboutMeTextEditingController;
  SharedPreferences preferences;
  String id = "";
  String nickname = "";
  String aboutMe = "";
  String photoUrl = "";
  File imageFileAvatar;
  final FocusNode nickNameFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode aboutMeFocusNode = FocusNode();

  readDataFromLocal() async {
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    id = preferences.getString("id");
    nickname = preferences.getString("nickname");
    aboutMe = preferences.getString("aboutMe");
    photoUrl = preferences.getString("photoUrl");

    nickNameTextEditingController = TextEditingController(text: nickname);
    aboutMeTextEditingController = TextEditingController(text: aboutMe);

    setState(() {

    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    readDataFromLocal();
  }

  Future getImage() async {
    ImagePicker tempImagePicker = ImagePicker();
    final getImage = await tempImagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    File newFileImage = File(getImage.path);

    if(newFileImage!=null) {
      setState(() {
        this.imageFileAvatar = newFileImage;
        isLoading = true;
      });
    }

    uploadImageToFirestoreAndStorage();
  }

  uploadImageToFirestoreAndStorage() async {
    String mFileName = id;
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    Reference storageReference = storage.ref().child(mFileName);
    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    UploadTask storageUploadTask = storageReference.putFile(imageFileAvatar);
    Reference ref;
    final newImageDownloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    photoUrl = newImageDownloadUrl;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(id).update({
      "photoUrl" : photoUrl,
      "aboutMe" : aboutMe,
      "nickname" : nickname,
    }).then((data) async {
      await preferences.setString("photoUrl", photoUrl);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Updated successfully");
    });

    // storageUploadTask.onComplete.then((value) {
    //   if(value.error==null) {
    //     storageTaskSnapshot = value;
    //     storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadUrl().then.((imageDownloadUrl) {
    //       photoUrl = imageDownloadUrl;
    //   });
    //   }
    // });
  }

  void updateData() {
    nickNameFocusNode.unfocus();
    aboutMeFocusNode.unfocus();

    setState(() {
      isLoading=false;
    });

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(id).update({
      "photoUrl" : photoUrl,
      "aboutMe" : aboutMe,
      "nickname" : nickname,
    }).then((data) async {

      await preferences.setString("photoUrl", photoUrl);
      await preferences.setString("aboutMe", aboutMe);
      await preferences.setString("nickname", nickname);

      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Updated successfully");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      imageFileAvatar==null
                          ? photoUrl != ""
                          ? Material(
                             child: CachedNetworkImage(
                               placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                                 child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                   strokeWidth: 2.0,
                                   valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                                 ),
                                 width: 200.0,
                                 height: 200.0,
                                 padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                               ),
                               imageUrl: photoUrl,
                               width: 200.0,
                               height: 200.0,
                               fit: BoxFit.cover,
                             ),
                             borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(125.0)),
                             clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                            )
                          : Icon(
                             Icons.account_circle, size: 90, color: Colors.grey,
                          )
                          : Material(
                            child: Image.file(
                              imageFileAvatar,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5,
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(125.0)),
                            clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                          ),
                      Positioned(
                        right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.01,
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.009,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.camera_alt,
                          ),
                          onPressed: getImage,
                          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                          highlightColor: Colors.white,
                          iconSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                width: double.infinity,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: isLoading ? circularProgress() : Container(),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      'Profile Name',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.04,
                      ),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 33.0),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Theme(
                      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "write a username...",
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white60,
                          ),
                        ),
                        controller: nickNameTextEditingController,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          nickname = value;
                        },
                        focusNode: nickNameFocusNode,
                      ),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      'Bio',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.04,
                      ),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 33.0, top: 30.0,),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Theme(
                      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Write about yourself...",
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white60,
                          ),
                        ),
                        controller: aboutMeTextEditingController,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          aboutMe = value;
                        },
                        focusNode: aboutMeFocusNode,
                      ),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.075,
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: TextButton(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 2.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Update',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.07,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                    overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                  onPressed: updateData,
                ),
              ),
            ],
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Please do check the lines  - 106-120, 129-142 and 144-173, 175-198, as on these lines, you may find the code for the arising problem, and you don't have to search for it**

Here are my logs -

```
I/fluttertelegra( 9924): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 6283(330KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3993KB/7987KB, paused 1.090ms total 114.133ms
D/UploadTask( 9924): Increasing chunk size to 524288
D/UploadTask( 9924): Increasing chunk size to 1048576
D/UploadTask( 9924): Increasing chunk size to 2097152
I/fluttertelegra( 9924): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 4870(2176KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(1624KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 8227KB/8227KB, paused 3.532ms total 119.502ms
I/fluttertelegra( 9924): Background concurrent copying GC freed 1139(152KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(260KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 7846KB/15MB, paused 11.888ms total 118.770ms
D/UploadTask( 9924): Increasing chunk size to 4194304
E/Toast   ( 9924): setGravity() shouldn't be called on text toasts, the values won't be used
E/Toast   ( 9924): setGravity() shouldn't be called on text toasts, the values won't be used
W/fluttertelegra( 9924): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed) 
E/Toast   ( 9924): setGravity() shouldn't be called on text toasts, the values won't be used
```

Comment: always share code snippets and not images

Comment: @griffins Yeah, actually I forgot by mistake. Else i always do upload.

Answer (score 1):

If you updated you dependencies it can be that you are using old syntax.

Could you try it with an updated syntax for uploading. Here is an example:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;

firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage =
    firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;

class StorageService {
  static Future<String> uploadFile(String path, File file) async {
    try {
      firebase_storage.Reference storageReference =
          firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(path);
      await storageReference.putFile(file);

      String downloadURL = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
      return downloadURL;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

You use it like this:

```dart
String photoURL = await StorageService.uploadFile(
        'users/${_auth.currentUser.uid}/${Path.basename(_image.path)}', _image);
```

Your function would look like this:

```dart
uploadImageToFirestoreAndStorage() async {
    String mFileName = id;
    Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('path_in_storage').child(mFileName);
    await storageReference.putFile(imageFileAvatar);

    String photoUrl = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();

    try{
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(id).update({
      "photoUrl": photoUrl,
      "aboutMe": aboutMe,
      "nickname": nickname,
    });
    }catch(e){
    print('e $e');
    }

    print('photoUrl $photoUrl');
    await preferences.setString("photoUrl", photoUrl);

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });

    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Updated successfully");
  }
```

These are my logs when i start updating my profile picture from gallary -

```
I/fluttertelegra( 9924): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 6283(330KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3993KB/7987KB, paused 1.090ms total 114.133ms
D/UploadTask( 9924): Increasing chunk size to 524288
D/UploadTask( 9924): Increasing chunk size to 1048576
D/UploadTask( 9924): Increasing chunk size to 2097152
I/fluttertelegra( 9924): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 4870(2176KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(1624KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 8227KB/8227KB, paused 3.532ms total 119.502ms
I/fluttertelegra( 9924): Background concurrent copying GC freed 1139(152KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(260KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 7846KB/15MB, paused 11.888ms total 118.770ms
D/UploadTask( 9924): Increasing chunk size to 4194304
E/Toast   ( 9924): setGravity() shouldn't be called on text toasts, the values won't be used
E/Toast   ( 9924): setGravity() shouldn't be called on text toasts, the values won't be used
W/fluttertelegra( 9924): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed) 
E/Toast   ( 9924): setGravity() shouldn't be called on text toasts, the values won't be used
```

Comment: I tried to use the updated code, but it didn't worked. A very very thank you for your help, but can you please tell me my mistake in the code above, as my image is not being updated, whereas my nickname and bio are. It would be very helpful.

Comment: I have update the answer. On the bottom is a version of your function that should work. If you don't want to upload the images in the rooth folder then just add a path where it should be uploaded.

Comment: It's still not working man. Again, it's not getting updated.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you have the proper rights to write to that path?

Comment: I have edited my post again, you can check the debugging details

Comment: Can you pls put the call for saving data to firestore in a `try/catch` as shown in the updated answer. If there is any kind of error we should see it in the console. Also check if the `donwloadURL` gets schon in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231911/discussion-between-shreyansh-sharma-and-tarik-huber).